# Prevent ubuntu server from updating to 16.04.3

Tags: server, apt, upgrade, updates

I've ran into a Problem as I was newly installing ubuntu server. I accidently shot my old install by removing the /etc/ folder completely. As all the scripts i had on the server were backed up onto my windows machine i figured i'd install the os fresh. But now when i run the `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt dist-upgrade`. I get updated to 16.04.3 which introduced a lot of new issues that I don't want to deal with. So I was wondering if I could update to a later 16.04.2 build and preventing ubuntu server from updating to 16.04.3. I just need security patches.
Thx in advance

Answer (score 1):

The number after the second point of LTS releases is really confusing.

If you initially install the 16.04 (without any points), it has the 4.4 kernel that will get security updates. But if you install regular updates the 16.04.3 version will be shown.

If you install a "point release", like 16.04.2 it has the 4.8 that is not supported during the full 16.04 life cycle. The 4.8 kernel is not supported any more, it will be upgraded to 4.10.

So if you want a "stable" release in terms of kernel and X.org drivers it is preferred to install the 16.04 version of Ubuntu. The 4.4 kernel will get security updates till 2021.

P.S. It is unclear what are the issues you "don't want to deal with". The most important difference is in the major kernel version.

Comment: Should have said what my issues are. My bad. Mainly support for amdgpu-pro driver are my issues. I need it to work but with the latest updates its not working properly anymore. Which i cant have. I also manually upgraded the Kernel to 4.10.x on my last install. Im not sure what the deal is about with 16.04.2 with the 4.8 kernel. Does that mean i dont get security updates ? Im pretty new to ubuntu and all this stuff. But idealy I'd like to go back to 16.04.2 and 4.10.x kernel

Comment: Your issue is with the kernel. But Iwhy do you need amdgpu-pro on a server?

Comment: Oh thats easy. Im not actually using ubuntu server as a server. Its just i was too lazy to rip out the gui stuff of ubuntu and for my doings ubuntu server was prefect. But yeah amd is stating on theyr website that 16.04.3 is causing issues http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDGPU-PRO-Driver-Compatibility-Advisory-with-Ubuntu-16.04.2-and-16.04.3.aspx . Since im so inexperienced with this i figured the update to .3 was the issue i have no clue about the specific of the updates. That's why i came here

Comment: You can install 16.04, or downgrade the kernel and xserver in the existing installation.

Comment: I've installed the kernel i used bevore. Which is the 4.10.9. Couldyou provide me with the command to downgrade Xserver?

Comment: `amdgpu` is not compatible with the `4.10.0-x` Ubuntu kernels. It looks like you installed a mainline kernel. The command is `sudo apt install xserver-xorg`, but I am afraid that won't fix anything.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the times there are only two version of a package available in Ubuntu repositories.

1. The main package with the version it was released in: `dist` like `xenial`.
2. The last updated version of the package either it `security` or `dist-updates` like: `xenial-updates`.
3. sometimes there is a difference between `security` and `dist-updates` which brings us to 3 different version.

Anyway, first all necessary packages to hold the state on 16.04.2 should exist, then you have to specifically choose between these 2 or 3 to install and after all hold these specific packages from being updated, which I believe introduces security concerns.

So If you update your packages, even through `upgrade` and not `dist-upgrade`, if not 100%, but you are updating almost > 90% of your packages to the last version, which will brings you to the 16.04.3.

Comment: That sucks... I guess i have to wait for 16.04.3 support for the stuff I use.